# 2d Transformation Syntax

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to do several animations on an element at one time. I want to `translate` the element to the correct cooridnates, which seems to be working, but I'm having trouble "growing" the height and width. With this syntax, the height and width don't seem to be animated, is my syntax off?

```
width: 230px;
height: 476px;
-webkit-transform: translate(492px, 0px);
transition: width 2s, height 2s, 0.5s;
-webkit-transition: width 2s, height 2s, 0.5s;
```

The goal is to move the position to the correct location in 0.5s, and have it expand to full height in 2s. Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you solved your question with mine answer ?

Comment: No. If I had, I would have marked it correct. I this syntax works as seen here: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/ZEJ9S/1/) , but I believe the problem I am having is adding it dynamically at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

You forget the "**type**" of the effect, see:

```
width: 230px;
height: 476px;
-webkit-transform: translate(492px, 0px);
transition: width 2s linear 0.5s, height 2s linear 0.5s;
-webkit-transition: width 2s linear 0.5s, height 2s linear 0.5s;
```

**But not setting the effect seems to change nothing, because it have a default one.**

I spotted that you used only webkit transition and not used the normal transition, see:

```
$("#box3.box").css({
    "-webkit-transform": "translate(-260px, -" + row1height + "px) scale(1)",
    "-webkit-transition-duration": "2s,2s,2s",
    "-webkit-transition-property": "height, width",
    "transform": "translate(-260px, -" + row1height + "px) scale(1)",
    "transition-duration": "2s,2s,2s",
    "transition-property": "height, width",        
    "height": "250px",
    "width": "250px"
});
```

Note that i used `-webkit-transition` and `transition`, because chrome seems to work only with `transition`.

Here is a updated [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZEJ9S/3/) with this working on Chrome